# What should i do with qtcreator process stub problem?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

i work with qtcreator .
and i make new project then run it , the problem in the photos happen and didn't disappear and gui or forms of the code
what should i do?[image]

[image]

Comment: So you are saying that all you get is this console window and you don't see your GUI application at all? Perhaps your antivirus is the problem.